# Tуториал по JSF

Tags: java, книги, jsf

Вечер добрый

Подкиньте кто ссылку на хороший русский туториал по JSF, желательно под IDE Eclipse

премного благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tutslink.blogspot.com/2012/04/jsf.html - Это для старта, если все же ограничиваться эклипсом.

А если нет то можно наглядненько посмотреть и послушать тут - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxNCqGAVy7Q

Comment: хех)) Ткач)
этот человек раньше в моем универе работал) Жаль я не застал его, говорят классный препод был. Спасибо)